# File IO - delete a line of text that contains a specific string C++

Tags: c++

I've written a function that reads in a text file, allows the user to pick an account to delete and deletes the specified account. What I need to do now is delete the line of text from the text file that lists the accounts on it. What good does it do to delete an account, but still have it show up in the list of accounts, right? Below is my code. What happens is that the entire contents of the account list text file get deleted, not just the line with the specific account number. The actual deletion of the account's text file works fine, it's just the deletion of that one line of text that is giving me trouble. Thanks for any assistance!

```
void UserInfo::deleteAccount() {
    vector<string> accounts;
    string line;
    char answer;
    ifstream acctList("accountList.txt");

    if (acctList.fail()) {
        cout << "There is a problem opening the file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    //populate vector with the list of accounts and display them.
    while (getline(acctList, line)) {
        accounts.push_back(line);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (accounts.size()); i++) {
        cout << accounts[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nEnter the account number of the account you would like to delete: ";
    cin >> acctNo;

    cout << "Are you sure you want to delete account number " << acctNo << "? ";
    cin >> answer;

    const char * result = (acctNo + ".txt").c_str(); //convert the selection choice to a c-string
    if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y') {

        if (remove(result) != 0)
            cout << "Unable to delete account." << endl;
        else
            cout << "\nThe account has been deleted successfully." << endl;
        //delete the account name and number from the list of accounts

        //temporary file to store the new list of accounts

        ofstream out("newAcctList.txt", ios::app);

        while (getline(acctList, line)) {
            if (line != acctNo)
                out << line << "\n";

            acctList.close();
            out.close();
            // delete the original file
        }
        if(out){
            remove("accountList.txt");
            // rename old to new
            rename("newAcctList.txt", "accountList.txt");
        } else {
            cout << "Error on output" << endl;
        }
    }//end if
```

Comment: You don't need to delete the file, just delete the slot in the vector and copy it over into the text file during output.

Comment: Give us an example of the input file please.

Comment: The "accountList.txt" file just has a string account type and a string account number on each line. It may have, say, 5 lines of text that represents 5 accounts. The user selects an account by account number to delete. The account text files themselves are saved by account number. So, the user enters the account number, which deletes the corresponding text file. I want to find the line of text containing the account number and delete it from my text file.

Answer (score 0):

You've already read `acctList` in the first `while` loop, so when you try to read it again to write `out`, it's already at the end.  You can just iterate over the `vector` `accounts` - throwing away the entry matching `acctNo` (which should be a local variable BTW) - instead of re-reading the file.

Comment: That sounds like something I could do. I'll give it a shot. I'll also make acctNo local. Thanks for the advice!